# Class instatiation with data

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, object-manager, object

I have created custom `Factory` class for my custom model class. Of course basically you can instantiate it by calling `$this->objectManager->create(Someobject::class);`. But, `ObjectManage` has also secoind argument `array $arguments`. Is it possible to do something like `$this->objectManager->create(SomeClass::class, $data);`, where `$data` is an array in order to populate object with some data during its creation? `SomeClass` inherits from `Magento\Framework\DataObject`.

When I tried call with second argument like above, object is generated, but with no data. After creation I can call `$object->setData($data)` and it works, but using second argument of `ObjectManager` seems to be much more elegant. Can anyone tell how to do it?